# Best practice/method for storing and displaying many Android drawable resources

Tags: android, bitmap

I am working on a revision to an app I currently have in production that allows users to select, drag and drop from hundreds of bitmap resources. The file size of the app is pretty dramatic, considering I have scaled versions for xhdpi and below.

I was wondering if there is a better way to store and display these resources, maybe like a tiled sheet? The average size of the xhdpi resource is approx 310x250. Any suggestions on how to keep the user experience the same/improved while also dropping the overall file size?

Answer (score 0):

If your drawables are vector graphics with a single color, you can [create a custom font where characters are actually the icons](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/). This might reduce a lot of data since you don't need to render images for different screen densities. It also has the advantage that you can dynamically change the color of the icons.

Tiling multiple icons into one image will not safe a lot of storage space. For websites it's mainly done to reduce the amount of HTTP requests which will speed up loading, but that is not an issue for local Android resources. If you do try this approach, keep in mind that there are limits to using large drawables. For instance, the Canvas has a getMaximumBitmapWidth() and getMaximumBitmapHeight() which specify these limits. An error will occur if you exceed these values.

Comment: They are not vector images they are all bitmaps. Good to know about tiling not being that helpful in regards to overall size.